# Solr At Runtime

Tags: windows, solr

Is there any way that we don't have to run solr_start.bat on runtime. Means I want the user to search their queries in a website using solr search server and I want to run solr_start.bat automatically at the back end. Please help me out.

Comment: Please provide some relevant detail. We should not have to guess about what you are running or what you are really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Solr on linux or windows?

This previous answer may help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically

Or this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531038/how-to-run-solr-on-a-windows-server-so-it-starts-up-automatically